# How to use an evaluated expression in SQL IN clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, in-clause

I have an application that takes a comma separated string for multiple IDs to be used in the 'IN' clause of a SQL query.

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [TABLENAME].[COLUMNNAME] 
    IN 
    ((SELECT '''' + REPLACE('PARAM(0, Enter ID/IDS. Separate multiple ids by 
    comma., String)', char(44), ''',''') + ''''))
```

I have tested that PARAM gets the string entered e.g. 'ID1, ID2' but SELECT/REPLACE does not execute. The statement becomes,

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [TABLENAME].[COLUMNNAME] 
    IN 
    ((SELECT '''' + REPLACE('ID1,ID2', char(44), ''',''') + ''''))
```

I am trying to achieve,

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [TABLENAME].[COLUMNNAME] 
    IN ('ID1', 'ID2')
```

The query does not return any results/errors. I am confident the corresponding records are in the database I am working with. Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like this. The `IN` operator expects a list of parameters separated by comma, but you supply it with a single parameter that happens to contain a comma delimited string:

If you are working on SQL Server version 2016 or higher, you can use the built in [`string_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to convert the delimited string into a table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE [TABLENAME].[COLUMNNAME] 
IN STRING_SPLIT(@CommaDelimitedString, ',')
```

For older versions, there are multiple user defined functions you can choose from, my personal favorite is Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). For more options, read Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way.](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)