# SQL Statement with Replace not working in IN Class

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below sql statement is not resulting any records.

```
Declare @sSelectedStates as nvarchar(500) = REPLACE('Bihar|Gujarat|Jharkhand','|',''',''')
select * from MyTable where State IN (@sSelectedStates)
```

This works

```
Declare @sSelectedStates as nvarchar(500) = REPLACE('Bihar','|',''',''')
select * from MyTable where State IN (@sSelectedStates)
```

This also works

```
Declare @sSelectedStates as nvarchar(500) = REPLACE('Gujarat','|',''',''')
select * from MyTable where State IN (@sSelectedStates)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Using the below statement I changed the database compatibility level

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
```

Comment: None of those work - you can't use a variable in an `IN` clause. The ones that work are only by accident because you only have a single value.

Comment: You have: `select * from MyTable where State IN ('Bihar,Gujarat,Jharkhand')`. This is one string. You are searching for all rows where the state is 'Bihar,Gujarat,Jharkhand'.

Comment: @Dale K, you were wrong.  I am getting result from 2nd and 3rd query using variable in In class.

Comment: Did you not understand the second sentence in Dale's comment?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner, I am using replace to make it as indivisuals.  Please check once again.

Comment: @Stu, Ok... Now I undetstood.  Please anyone let me know how to handle this?

Comment: Use `STRING_SPLIT`. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a common misconception, `in` works on a *set* not a *string* - it does not parse the single string you are providing in any way.

You can provide a *set* of values to the `in` clause by splitting the string into rows:

```
Declare @sSelectedStates nvarchar(500) = 'Bihar|Gujarat|Jharkhand';

select * 
from MyTable 
where State in (select * from String_Split(@sSelectedStates, '|'));
```

Comment: Getting this error. Invalid object name 'String_Split'.

Comment: Using SQL Server 2015

Comment: There's no 2015 version of SQL Server. supported versions are 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022. Older versions include 2008, 2005, 2000, 7.0 and so on. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server

Comment: Yes its 2016.  I changed the compatibility level and its worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like this. The `IN` operator expects a list of parameters separated by comma, but you supply it with a single parameter that happens to contain a comma delimited string.

A scalar variable can only contain a single value - and when the `IN` operator is presented with a single value, it acts like the `=` operator - so your queries are basically the same as these:

```
select * from MyTable where State = 'Bihar'',''Gujarat'',''Jharkhand'

select * from MyTable where State = Bihar

select * from MyTable where State = Gujarat
```

If you're working with SQL Server 2016 or higher, you can use the built in [`string_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to convert the delimited string into a table.
If you're working on a lower version, you can use a user-defined function to split the string for you.

Comment: I am getting the state names from a variable.  So cant use it directly in where class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49849515/3094533 This is a basically similar answer to a basically similar question I've once written. It has links to string-splitting UDFs that can be used in SQL Server versions that predates the 2016 version.